# How do you return data from a view to controller in asp.net using foreign key relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

There are two tables Roles and Administrator. I have a foreign key in the administrator table which references to the RoleId. So, I performed linq query to get all the roles and admin data from the SQL server. Then in the MVC App of the asp.net, I created two model classes as shown below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FastFactsTestPortalMVCApp.Models
{
    public class Administrator
    {
        public int AdminId { get; set; }
        public string AdminFirstName { get; set; }
        public string AdminLastName { get; set; }
        public string AdminEmail { get; set; }
        public string AdminUserName { get; set; }
        public string AdminPassword { get; set; }
        public string AdminContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string AdminDesignation { get; set; }
        public int AdminRoleId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model Role Class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FastFactsTestPortalMVCApp.Models
{
    public class Role
    {
        public Role()
        {
            this.Administrators = new HashSet<Administrator>();
            this.HRs = new HashSet<HR>();
        }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<HR> HRs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then using admin controller, I wanted to register a user. In that case I wanted to create a view, where i retrieve data of roles from linq query and display the role name, so that the user can register with the role name.

For that I used Create Function which is given below in the admin controller:

```
      [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult RegisterAdmin()
        {
            FastFactsTestPortalRepository repObj = new FastFactsTestPortalRepository();
            ViewBag.RoleId = repObj.GetRoles();
            
            return View();
           

        }
```

Then I coded a function to save the input values from the user :

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SaveRegisteredAdmin(Models.Administrator userObj)
        {
             if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                FastFactsTestPortalRepository repObj = new FastFactsTestPortalRepository();
                
                var returnValue = repObj.AddAdmin(userObj);
                if(returnValue)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Error");
                }
              
            }
            return View("RegisterAdmin");
        }
```

For the Register Admin, I created a View also, where the error exists. The error in the view says Null after registering the or clicking on the submit button. The null error was referred to DropDownList.

The Code is given below:

```
@model FastFactsTestPortalMVCApp.Models.Administrator

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RegisterAdmin";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<h2>RegisterAdmin</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRegisteredAdmin","Admin")) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Administrator</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminFirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminFirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminFirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminLastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminLastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminUserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminUserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminUserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminContactNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminContactNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminDesignation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminDesignation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminDesignation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminRoleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AdminRoleId, new SelectList(Model.Role.Administrators, "RoleId", "RoleName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminRoleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I basically wanted to Register a user with his/her role name, but which is a foreign key relationship. Since I tried many ways. I am not able to find the right method. I would love to have the support or guidance to understand the concept and correct my mistake too.

Answer (score 0):

> For the Register Admin, I created a View also, where the error exists.
> The error in the view says Null after registering the or clicking on
> the submit button. The null error was referred to DropDownList.
>
> ```
> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AdminRoleId, new SelectList(Model.Role.Administrators, "RoleId", "RoleName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
> ```

According to your description, I think the issue is related to above code, it uses Model binding method to bind the DropDownList, but in the RegisterAdmin Action method, we can see you are using ViewBag to store the roles, and didn't return the Administrator object. So, when you binding model to DropDownList, the Role is null, it will throw the null exception.

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult RegisterAdmin()
    {
        FastFactsTestPortalRepository repObj = new FastFactsTestPortalRepository();
        ViewBag.RoleId = repObj.GetRoles(); 
        return View(); 
    }
```

To solve this issue, you could use the ViewBag to bind the DropDownList, code as below:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AdminRoleId, new SelectList(ViewBag.RoleId, "RoleId", "RoleName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Note: Before return the view, you could check the ViewBag.RoleId, make sure it contain all roles.

The following code works well on my side, you could refer it:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult RegisterAdmin()
    {
        //FastFactsTestPortalRepository repObj = new FastFactsTestPortalRepository();
        //ViewBag.RoleId = repObj.GetRoles();
        List<Role> rolelist = new List<Role>()
        {
            new Role(){ RoleId =1001, RoleName="Admin"},
            new Role(){ RoleId = 1002, RoleName="Developer"},
            new Role(){RoleId = 1003, RoleName = "User"}
        };
        ViewBag.RoleId = rolelist;
        return View(); 
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveRegisteredAdmin(Models.Administrator userObj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {   
        }
        List<Role> rolelist = new List<Role>()
        {
            new Role(){ RoleId =1001, RoleName="Admin"},
            new Role(){ RoleId = 1002, RoleName="Developer"},
            new Role(){RoleId = 1003, RoleName = "User"}
        };
        ViewBag.Role = rolelist;

        return View("RegisterAdmin");
    }
```

The output as below:

[image]

Comment: I just set a debugger to check the submitted value, as we can see, we could get the RoleId value, then, we could according this ID property to find the role and do something.

Answer (score 0):

I rectified the error using the following code in the view :

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminRoleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AdminRoleId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Rolelist, "RoleId", "RoleName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminRoleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            </div>
```